# Textbox ForeColor change in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

Situation:  I have a form in `MS Access 2010` containing around 50 textboxes and combo-boxes that have their `ForeColor` set to `11250603 Gray` on `Load`. What I want to do is create a single piece of succinct code that changes the `ForeColor` of the  to `vbBlack` on individual selection.

I could use the `GotFocus` event for each text/combo but this is clumsy.  I have seen other threads that are vaguely similar that have used `DirectCast()` but it's not something I know and I'm not even sure it will work in `MS Access 2010`.  I have tried YouTube and searching threads here but haven't found a solution so far.

If somebody could point me in the right direction as to where I could find code or where I could adapt code, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not using Conditional formatting ? (look Ma, no programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use *WithEvents*. An example is here:

[Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html)

It contains this simple code:

```
Private Sub ClassTextBox_Click()

    ' Select full content.
    ClassTextBox.SelStart = 0
    ClassTextBox.SelLength = Len(ClassTextBox.Value)
    ' Display the clicked value.
    ClassTextBox.Parent!CopyClicked.Value = ClassTextBox.Value
    ' Copy the clicked value to the clipboard.
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

End Sub
```

to select and copy a value for any textbox clicked. You would modify that to instead *set the ForeGround colour*:

```
Private Sub ClassTextBox_Click()

    ' Set foreground colour.
    ClassTextBox.ForeColor = vbBlack

End Sub
```

In the *Load* event, you would set the foreground colour to your grey value.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I will read the full article and endeavour to adapt it to my needs.

Comment: Hi Gustav, would I be right in thinking that if I want to change the `BackColor` whilst `GotFocus`, I would need to create a separate `Sub` for `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` and declare a `variable` for the `BackColor` in a similar way to John Colby did?

Comment: I guess so, though I don't have the code present. Should be easy to check out.